# TableViews inside ScrollView Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xamarin, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a View that contains many subviews and can contain many tableviews.

[image]

Need is to enable scroll of all the subviews. 
Actually I created scroll view and put it into superView. Then i put all the views inside that scroll but i have a lot of problems with putting tableviews inside that scroll using AutoLayout. I dont want a scroll inside tableViews, all i need is to enable clicks each tableView i create.  I would like to listen to all of your suggestions how can I easily create this View.

Answer (score 1):

A scrollview inside of a scrollview is hard to handle. Maybe it's worth to redesign your data model by combine the contents?

e.g. (assuming that each table contains 2 Labels)

- image -> Row cell 0 of type A OR TableHeader
- Label -> Row cell 1 of type B
- Label -> Row cell 2 of type B
- Label -> Row cell 3 of type B
- Label -> Row cell 4 of type B
- Table 1 Label 1 -> Row cell 5 of type C
- Table 1 Label 2 -> Row cell 6 of type C
- Label -> Row cell 7 of type B
- Table 2 Label 1 -> Row cell 8 of type C
- Table 2 Label 2 -> Row cell 9 of type C
- Label -> Row cell 10 of type B
- Table 3 Label 1 -> Row cell 11 of type C
- Table 3 Label 2 -> Row cell 12 of type C
  ...
- Button -> Row cell n of type D OR TableFooter

Now you can fill your table like a normal table without special solution.

Comment: The problem of a scrollview inside of another is that it isn't flexible in content height anymore. Lets say the outer scrollview has a content height = screen height, the inner scrollviews do not know about it. Therefore you have to define the the inner scrollview height to maximum content height. The cell loading mechanism know has to load the whole table even if only 1pt height needs display. Therefore you lose the reuse loading advantages.

Comment: @codealchmist yes thats why im asking for another solution

Comment: Thanks for suggest, I will try your solution and give a reply! :)

Comment: @codealchmist 
Assuming how will behave tableview inside tableview. I mean its like putting scrollview inside another scrollview, so its what u did not suggest to do.